# How to return data with its data from a apivot table as a JSON response?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models `User` and `Role` generated by a `laratrust` package. So, now I need to get all `roles` for all `users`.

**Here's my code of getting such data:**

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user) {
    foreach($user->roles as $role) {

    }  
}

return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'users' => $users,
]);
```

Such a way gives the data I need.

[image]

But I guess empty `foreach` isn't correct way to get the data. What're the other ways of getting such data?

Comment: `$role` inside foreach is your role data, what else you need??

Comment: @Sohel0415 my `foreach` loop's are empty. For me it's weird. So, I guess it's not a correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eager load roles with

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();

// or
// $users = User::get();
// $users->load('roles');

return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'users' => $users,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use of foreach you can simply do this

```
$users = User::all();
if($users)
{
    foreach($users as $user) {
        foreach($user->roles as $role) {

        }  
    }
}
else {
   // No result
}

return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'users' => $users,
]); 

I hope it helps you.
```

Comment: Yeah ur way is correct, BUT in `blade` templates)) I use `vue.js` to show the data, because I'm making an `axios` call.

Comment: Then add condition around foreach loop in controller. I edited my answer please check